# Junit for application using Struts, Springs, Hibernate all

Tags: spring, hibernate, junit, struts2, mocking

Is there any specific approach already defined or used by any one for unit testing applications using Struts, Springs, Hibernate technologies ? 
What are different mocking apis we can use ?
Note: I don't want want any solution to individually unit test these technologies.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject mock Spring facades into your Struts actions, and unit-test the Struts actions. You can inject mock Spring repositories/DAOs into your Spring facades and unit-test these facades. And you can use DBUnit (or another similar tool) to populate a test database before each repository test.

Choose the mocking API you like the most. There are sevaral ones: Mockito, EasyMock, JMock, etc.

If you want to test the whole app, you're not doing unit tests anymore, but integration tests. And mocking would go against your goal. If that's what you want to do, you could use Selenium or HtmlUnit to test the application.